# Auto Post in CRM not reflecting entity name change

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I have renamed the account entity to "Organisation", I exported the Translations and updated all the references to Account in the Translation file and re-imported it and published all my customisations

Yet, when I create a new Organisation record, I still get an Auto Post on the my wall saying "Account: Created By ..." instead of "Organisation: Created By ..."

I am using CRM Online.

Any suggestions?

Comment: These messages seem to be controlled by *Activity Feeds Configuration* but I couldn't get it to change the display name when I tried on my system. [Others have run into this as well](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/146594) but there's no solution to be found.